# JFrame keeps application running even after closing

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jframe

I have a class with only static methods and one of them opens a JOptionPane error message dialogue using a JFrame object as component.

This is the class + method:

```
public class miscMethods
{
    static JFrame errorWindow = null;

    public static void ErrorPopup(String message)
    {
        errorWindow = new JFrame();
        errorWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        errorWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(errorWindow, message, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        errorWindow = null;
    }
}
```

The ErrorPopup method is used inside a JavaFX controller and other places, called like this:

```
import static code.miscMethods.ErrorPopup;
...
ErrorPopup("This is the error message");
```

Problem is that the application's process won't close when I close the the program from the window's ✕ after the popup appears, because the JFrame was created and shown.
I know the JFrame is the culprit, so I added the `errorWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`
but it doesn't seem to do anything, since the program isn't closing.

In this question: [JFrame and why stay running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486279/jframe-and-why-stay-running)
The accepted answer talks about non-daemon threads, but the only thread I open is a daemon one, so unless JavaFX open one then it can't be that I believe.

So, why does the process keep running and how can I solve it?

I'm still new to Java so if I made a mistake and/or my code shows bad practices please do point them out!

Edit: I'm using a JFrame because I need the setAlwaysOnTop, since using
`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);` opens it not on top of the JavaFX window. If there's a better way let me know.

Comment: Any reason why you running JavaFX and Swing together?  Both Swing and JavaFX have their threads

Comment: *"I'm using a JFrame because ..."* But if you're using JavaFX, you shouldn't be using `JOptionPane` at all, you should use `Alert`. I strongly recommend you pick one toolkit (Swing or JavaFX) and use it exclusively.

Comment: Yea you guys are right. I don't know why i Switched to Swing in the first place, anyway I took out the JFrame stuff and put in the Alert and it's alert.show and it's working. Could've avoided all this JFrame stuff but at least I learned something new for the future. Thanks everyone for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
errorWindow = null;
```

does nothing of use since the object is still displayed. You want this instead:

```
errorWindow.dispose();
```

Actually, even better, simply get rid of `errorWindow` altogether and pass `null` as the first parameter to the JOptionPane.

Comment: Wow that must be the fastest answer I've ever seen. It seems to be working too!
I'll accept the answer after the 10minutes limit if it really solve the problem. Thanks though!

Comment: @Destard20: listen to MadProgrammer

Comment: Just to make this clear. JOptionPane is NOT JavaFX! So why do you use that in the first place. (Others have asked the same already but in a less explicit way.)

Comment: In the past I was using javafx.scene.control.Alert, but then switched it for this other approach. I cannot recall exactly why the switch, but it may have been because the static class was having troubles accessing javaFX, it was probably something I was doing wrong at the time though.